# delegate different-than-click-event function ajax load .on() jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `lazy-image` Jquery Script that doesnt pass after ajax load.

**HTML**

```
 <ul id=results></ul>
      <li><img src='px.jpg' data-src='image.jpg'  /></li>
      <li><img src='px.jpg' data-src='image.jpg'  /></li>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  setTimeout( function(){
     $('.lazy-img').each(function() {this.src = $(this).data('src'); 
  }).removeAttr('data-src');
    }, 800);
```

I know that when the event is `click` I delegate it to the container `results`,

```
   $('#results').on('click','.className', function);
```

In this case this `lazy-image` have to work after the loading is done. How should I delegate it?

Comment: use `$(window).on('load', function)`

Comment: So are you saying you are dynamically creating the img tags that should be lazy loaded, after the page has finished loading?

Comment: @Taplar Yes. `$(window).on('load', function)` doesnt work when the data is loaded by ajax

Comment: You will have to either execute the logic inside the timeout after appending the new elements to the page, or put that timeout logic in a method that you call after the new elements are added to the page.

Comment: I undetstand the point but Do I delegate by doing that? what about trigger, can I put this even within an `on()`?

Comment: No, this is not a delegate issue.  You are not trying to bind on an event for future elements.  You are trying to execute logic on elements once they exist.  There is not an event there.

Comment: I see the point....I dont know how to make it work with the loaded data, though

Comment: What do you mean.  Just execute your each logic again, but use the selector `$('.lazy-img[data-src]')` for it.

Comment: I make it work but I have to attach the same code within the load-from page. I just want to define it once

Comment: So make a function an call it in both places.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. But I know I can call it once.

Comment: You could change that `setTimeout` to a `setInterval` and change the selector in it to `$('.lazy-img[data-src]')`, but just be aware that an interval will not stop until you manually stop it or leave the page.